# Angular6 Promise fired twice

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I am building an angular app and I have a problem with my login. My login function is fired twice and I don't know why.

My AuthenticationService method is like:

```
public login(body: any): PromiseLike<any> {
return this.http
  .post(`${environment.baseApi}/login`, body)
  .pipe(
    catchError((e) => this.handleErrorLog(e, true))
  )
  .toPromise();
}
```

My LoginComponent is like:

```
public login() {
this.loginUser.username = this.username;
this.loginUser.password = this.password;

this.authService.login(this.loginUser).then((data) => {
  console.log("login...");
  this.loginSuccessful(data);
});
```

}

My html button is like:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block login-btn" type="submit" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="login()">Login</button>
```

The login is working but when I click on the button to log in, the request is fired twice. Anybody knows why?

Comment: Is there one request of type `OPTIONS` ?

Comment: what do you mean? I think i havent any request with type OPTIONS

Comment: Promise will not fire on options.

Comment: I mean, when you look at your network tab, is one of the requests using the `OPTIONS` verb instead of `GET | POST | PUT | DELETE`

Comment: if you have form tag with `(ngSubmit)="login()"`, then remove `(click)="login()"` from button tag

Comment: @Antoniossss that's not a promise per se, that's an observable transformed into a promise.

Comment: Indead there is one request with OPTIONS, but also one with POST

Comment: Does not matter, it wont fire on options and still - promise is promise, does not matter whats underneeth.

Comment: @Antoniossss then strange that he does have an options request ... OP, `OPTIONS` requests are used to test an endpoint. [See more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/M%C3%A9thode/OPTIONS), and worry not about them, as they won't bother you.

Comment: @Sarthak Aggarwal. Your answer is the right one! I deleted (click) function of my button and now it fires only one request

Comment: @trichetriche its strange how? You have no idea what request is actually beeing made nor where is the endpoint. So how can you say its bizzare or not without knowing the facts that actually decides about sending options or not?

Comment: Post your answer and i will accept it as the right one. It has nothing to do with my promises ot the way i build my service. It was the second call from my button. I had (ngSubmit)="login()" in my form and (click)="login()" in my button. That was the reason i ha two calls.

Comment: @Antoniossss he says he has an options request, and I didn't want to say things I'm not sure of, but I have never heard about promises not making options requests. And I know what request is made, and I'm not sure the URL has something to do with it.

Comment: So the reason is what I was thinking -yo uare invoking it twice. Simple as that.

Comment: *but I have never heard about promises not making options requests.* See, that is the culrprit, as you think that OPTIONS are made by Promises or anything like that. Well to your knowledge, OPTIONS (can be done manully but who would bother) are made as preflight BY THE BROWSER outside of scope of application. App does not even know that preflight is beeing made nor have any influence on that (besides obvious things like using so called "simple requests"  and to the same domain)

Comment: I vote for closing as it is simple mistake.

Comment: Why are you even promising this?

Comment: @Antoniossss yeah try to calm down buddy. I realize I have misread your first comment where you said `promise will not fire on options`, I missed the "on". I know options requests are related to cors issues, so keep it classy and chill please.

Comment: @Antoniossss and I've said it's weird because he said himself there is an OPTIONS request. He said "the request is fired twice", not "I am seeing the console log twice", and he didn't provide the code related to his form. So yeah, like other people, I tried to find the issue. Sorry that I wanted to help, next time I'll ask for your permission and your review on my comment before posting ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `(ngSubmit)="login()"` in your *form* tag and `(click)="login()"` in your *button* tag, then your *login()* will fire twice

Therefore make the following changes in your **.component.html** file

```
<form (ngSubmit)="login()">
    // Rest of form
  <button type="submit" >Login</button> // --> remove (click)="login()"
</form>
```